# Pass ui (tapped) event thru control to another

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

In My Windows Store App (c#, xaml) I need to pass one ui event thru one control to another. 
 My xaml looks like:

```
 <Grid x:Name="FirstGrid" Width="100" Height="100" Tapped="FirstGrid_OnTapped" Background="Black"/>
 <Grid x:Name="SecondGrid" Width="100" Height="100" Tapped="SecondGrid_OnTapped" Background="Black"/>
```

This is 2 identical grids which located one on one.

My c# code looks like:

```
    private void FirstGrid_OnTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("FirstGrid_OnTapped");
    }

    private void SecondGrid_OnTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("SecondGrid_OnTapped");
        e.Handled = false;
    }
```

And when I tapped on this grids - `SecondGrid_OnTapped` methods works, and I hoped that    `e.Handled = false;` line says to system: "pass event on virtual tree" and `FirstGrid_OnTapped` should works too - but it does not work.

Question: How I can pass event from one control to another, which is on the same level in the virtual tree?

note: code - it's just sample to explain what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to pass the event from one to another?

If the second control just wants to listen to that event whether or not it's been handled then add this code to your code behind in the OnLoaded of your second grid.

```
Grid1.AddHandler(TappedEvent, new TappedEventHandler((s, args) =>
        {
            //respond to tapped event 
        }), true);
```

The third parameter means the event handler will respond to Handled events as well as unhandled events.